# Custom Twig Function Not Recognized

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

I have a twig/timber function and the code doesn't shows any error but when I go to use function in my twig template there is an error saying '' is not a function.

This is what I have in my fucntions.php file in the twig template:

```
add_filter( 'timber/twig', function( \Twig_Environment $twig ) {
    $twig->addFunction( new Twig_Function( 'get_custom_meta', 'get_custom_meta' ) );
```

} );

```
function get_custom_meta($key,$id){
    if(empty($id)){
       return types_render_field($key,array("raw"=>"true","separator"=>";"));
    }else{
       return get_post_meta( $id, 'wpcf-'.$key, true );
    }
}
```

and this is how I'm calling the function in the template.

```
{{ function(get_custom_meta('facebook', event.post_id )) }}
```

This in in wordpress. Thanks

Comment: What does get_custom_meta return? I believe that the return is empty.

Answer (score 2):

```
{{ get_custom_meta('facebook', event.post_id ) }}
```

I think you access functions like this rather than through function()

```
/**
 * My custom Twig functionality.
 *
 * @param Twig_Environment $twig
 * @return $twig
 */
add_filter( 'timber/twig', function( \Twig_Environment $twig ) {
    $twig->addFunction( new Twig_Function( 'edit_post_link', 'edit_post_link' ) );
} );
```

when you make a function available in Twig by using Timber\Twig_Function inside the timber/twig hook like this you use it like that

```
{# single.twig #}
<div class="admin-tools">
    {{ edit_post_link }}
</div>
{# Calls edit_post_link using default arguments #}

{# single-my-post-type.twig #}
<div class="admin-tools">
    {{ edit_post_link(null, '<span class="edit-my-post-type-link">') }}
</div>
{# Calls edit_post_link with all defaults, except for second argument #}
```

the function() is for wordpress functions

refer to:
[timber twig functions](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/functions/)

Comment: Either way the function is not recognized

Comment: If you have functions that you use a lot and want to improve readability of your code, you can make a function available in Twig by using Timber\Twig_Function inside the timber/twig hook.

have you done that?

https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/functions/

Comment: Am I supposed to add the function to the specific view?

Comment: @MattStacey maybe try https://github.com/timber/timber/wiki/WP-Integration#functions 

Read on function wrapper, it might help

Comment: I think function wrapper is deprecated

Comment: I think the solution is correct. @MattStacey, you can either use `{{ get_custom_meta('facebook', event.post_id ) }}` instead of `{{ function(get_custom_meta('facebook', event.post_id )) }}` or call the function with `{{ function('get_custom_meta', 'facebook', event.post_id )) }}`. To clear things up: The `function_wrapper()` function is **deprecated** since Timber 1.3.0. An up-to-date guide can be found in the [Functions Guide](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/functions/) of the official documentation. The entries in the wiki are deprecated as well and will be deleted soon.

Comment: @Cezary `function()` in Twig is not only for WordPress functions, but for all functions available in PHP at the time the it is called.