# Timber - extend data to context (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

So I'm trying to make this functions data available to each context there this, but I'm stuck with how to actually get the data itself now that its part of the context.

I have the following:

```
add_filter( 'timber_context', 'fancySquares_get_instagram_images'  );

 function fancySquares_get_instagram_images( $context ) {

  $context['instaImages'] = [];

  $api = wp_remote_request("testUrlHere");
  $api = json_decode($api['body']);


  for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++)
    {
      $images[$i] = [];
      $images[$i]['image'] = $api->data[$i]->images->standard_resolution->url;
      $images[$i]['url'] = $api->data[$i]->link;
      $images[$i]['likes'] = $api->data[$i]->likes->count;
    }

    return $context;

}
```

I am them trying to print out the result to make sure I'm doing it right, it returns an empty **Array()**:

```
{{ instaImages|print_r}}
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Filters are to transform data, you need to add a function and then to something like `{% set images = get_instagram() %}`. Note the first argument in `add_filter` or `add_function` is the name of the filter/function that will be available in `twig`

Comment: Hey @DarkBee thanks!  But I think I maybe more confused now.  I tried the addFunction example in Twigs documention, but I got errors related to twig not being defined, is that because of Timber?

I've also seen Extending Timber, but I can't get the function to return https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/extending-timber/

Comment: Hi RMH seems i'm mistaken about the sytanx. You can find the proper one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45674040/446594)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the for the above question, hope this helps someone in the future.

You'll add the filter:

- inside the function passed to the filter, you'll set the CONTEXT variable to the function where you'll run all your magic
- and then return the CONTEXT so you can use it throughout the site at your discretion

code sample:

```
add_filter( 'timber_context', 'fancySquares_show_instagram_results'  );

function fancySquares_show_instagram_results( $context ) {
    $context['fancySquaresInstagram'] = fancySquares_get_instagram();
    return $context;
}


function fancySquares_get_instagram()
{
  if(get_transient('instagram')) 
    {
        return get_transient('instagram');
    } 
    else 
    {
      $api = wp_remote_request("instagram-api-url");
      $api = json_decode($api['body']);
      $images = [];

      for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++)
      {
        $images[$i] = [];
        $images[$i]['image'] = $api->data[$i]->images->standard_resolution->url;
        $images[$i]['url'] = $api->data[$i]->link;
        $images[$i]['likes'] = $api->data[$i]->likes->count;
      }


        set_transient('instagram', $images, 60*60*24); // expires every day
        return $images;
    }

}
```

You will then output with:

```
{% for insta in fancySquaresInstagram %}

    {{insta['url']}}

  {% endfor %}
```

or could print the whole thing to get a better idea of whats inside:

```
{{ fancySquaresInstagram|print_r }}
```