# Twig + wordpress - how to get filemtime for style.css

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I'm using twig + timber in my wordpress theme. I have style.css file included in this way

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.theme.uri }}/dist/css/style.min.css" />
```

I want to add `?ver=xxxx` to prevent file caching. My question is how to implement filemtime function? I want to make it like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.theme.uri }}/dist/css/style.min.css?ver=1202120210" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can handle this, and both involve writing some PHP.

The first way, and the one I'd recommend, is to use [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) instead of adding the `<link>` tag into your twig file.

```php
/**
 * Places the following tag into the page <head>, where
 *  `{ theme_url }` = the url of your theme directory
 *  `{ filemtime }` = the timestamp of the last modified date
 *                    for the stylesheet
 * <link rel="stylesheet" href="{ theme_url }/dist/css/style.min.css?ver={ filemtime }" />
 */
function my_custom_css_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'main-styles',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/css/style.min.css',
        array(),
        filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/dist/css/style.min.css'),
        false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_css_styles' );
```

You can put multiple stylesheets into the function if you need to, and you can include logic to load them conditionally based on post type, post ID, or anything that you can determine about the current page using PHP.

If this does not work for you for some reason, the second method is to generate your version number with PHP and then add it as a new variable to your Timber context. Your line in Twig would look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.theme.uri }}/dist/css/style.min.css?ver={{ style_css_version }}" />
```

Then in your template file you would add the new `style_css_version` variable after defining the context:

```php
$context = Timber::get_context();
$context['style_css_version'] = filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/dist/css/style.min.css');
```

If you want to use this on every page on your site, not just pages with a specific template, you can add it to the global Timber context from your `functions.php` (more information at [Timber - extend data to context (WordPress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47229352/timber-extend-data-to-context-wordpress)):

```php
function my_custom_timber_context( $context ) {
    $context['style_css_version'] = filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/dist/css/style.min.css');
}

add_filter( 'timber_context', 'my_custom_timber_context'  );
```

Comment: For some reason I need to use the non proper way. I added filemtime to my add_to_context function add_to_context('style_version', filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/dist/css/style.min.css')); and I works. But I have another problem. My css file is minifed, when I add ?ver=xxxx file is unminifed. Why it's that? How Can I have both, minified css with versioning?

Comment: Hmm, I can't think of any reason that would be related to Timber. You should probably post a new question in the Wordpress development category.

Comment: problem was solved. It was my mistake. I didn't run one of grunt task responsible for minification

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this approach for flexibility.

**functions.php**

```
/**
 * versioned_theme_uri() Twig Function
 *
 * Create an auto-versioned URI for a relative theme file.
 *
 * @param \Twig\Environment $twig The Twig environment.
 * @return \Twig\Environment
 */
function kevinlearynet_extend_timber_twig($twig) {
  $twig_function = new Timber\Twig_Function( 'theme_uri_versioned', function ($theme_file) {
    $uri = get_theme_file_uri( $theme_file );
    $filepath = get_theme_file_path( $theme_file );
    $version = file_exists( $filepath ) ? filemtime( $filepath ) : 'FILE_NOT_FOUND';

    return "$uri?v=$version";
  } );

  $twig->addFunction( $twig_function );

  return $twig;
}
add_filter( 'timber/twig', 'kevinlearynet_extend_timber_twig' );
```

**Theme .twig template**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ theme_uri_versioned('dist/app.min.js') }}" type="text/css" media="all" />
```